# Failed to create a Network Interface with no much information except a CloudException

Tags: java, azure, automation, azure-web-app-service

I used to have this piece of code and it used to work for a while ..suddenly I am having an issue with the Interface .create api call, it's throwing a Cloud exception with no further details.
At least what is the proper way to debug this.. ?!

```
NetworkInterface networkInterface = azure.networkInterfaces()
                .define(netInterfaceName)
                .withRegion(region)
                .withExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
                .withExistingPrimaryNetwork(azure.networks().getByGroup(resourceGroupName, network))
                .withSubnet(networkSubnet)
                .withPrimaryPrivateIpAddressDynamic()
                .withNewPrimaryPublicIpAddress()
                .withExistingNetworkSecurityGroup(azure.networkSecurityGroups().getByGroup(resourceGroupName, securityGroup))
                .create();

VirtualMachine automationVM = azure.virtualMachines().define(vmName)
                    .withRegion(region)
                    .withExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
                    .withExistingPrimaryNetworkInterface(networkInterface)
                    .withLatestWindowsImage(vmImage.publisher(), vmImage.offer(), vmImage.sku())
                    .withAdminUsername("ABC")
                    .withAdminPassword("XYZ!")
                    .withSize(azureCores.size())
                    .create();
```

Comment: Please remove the azure-search tag as this question is unrelated to Azure Search.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion for debugging, please try to use `Fiddler` to catch the request & response of the calling of REST API which be wrapped within Azure Java SDK. Then you can refer to [Azure Network REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network/) to find out the reason of the issue to adjust your code to make it works. Meanwhile, there are many [sample codes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/azure-samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management) for using Azure Java SDK, which I think they are great reference valuable for you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the replay Peter, I read most to of the samples regarding creating the network interfaces. I will try to integrate Fiddler into Intellij,

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I reached the limit with the number of public IP addresses but it was not clear from the subnet. The subnet doesn't tell you that you are out of Public ip addresses.